# Conditionally render component on specific route and viewport height

Tags: reactjs

**GOAL:** When on `/` route and viewport height is over 1000px, do not render the navigation component.

The `Navigation` component should, however, render on every other route (e.g., `affiliate-code`, `dashboard`, `editor`, etc.

Any ideas how I can do this?

```js
{user.uid && (
          <Route
            path={[
              "/affiliate-code",
              "/dashboard",
              "/editor",
              "/locked",
              "/saved",
              "/notifications",
              "/stats",
              "/create-page",
              "/",
            ]}
            component={() =>
              !["/send-invite", "/:id"].includes(window.location.pathname) && (
                <Navigation
                  key={window.location.pathname}
                  newNotification={newNotification}
                />
              )
            }
          />
        )}
```

Comment: Which Routing library are you using?

Comment: @DejanSandic React router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, since you are using `ReactRouter` i suggest using a hook it provides to check the current route reactively.

Also, I suggest you install `react-use` so you could use their hook to check for the window height reactively. This will enable you to hide your navbar if someone makes the screen smaller after the initial load.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useMedia } from 'react-use';

export const Navigation = ({ newNotification }) => {
    let { pathname } = useLocation();
    const isTallEnough = useMedia('(min-height: 1000px)');

    if (pathname !== '/' || !isTallEnough) return null;

    return (
        <div>
            ...your navigation
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Awesome, however, when I add /:id to the list of pathnames I don't want to render the nav bar on, it still shows. Any idea? Just updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the hooks react-router provides.
Here is the link: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

You have four of them, one should enable you to get an exact match of the `/` path:

- useHistory
- useLocation
- useParams
- useRouteMatch

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! This saved me :p

Comment: NP, happy to help